# Is the reddit api restricting me from grabbing pictures?

Tags: python, flask, reddit

I have a web app that gets a picture from any subreddit with pics, and I just click next and cycle through pictures. 3/5 of them won't load, I know there is some restriction that I can't make more than 1 request a second or something, but I can wait more than a few seconds and it still can fail to load an image. What could this be?

Comment: This seems more along the lines of taking it up with Reddit rather than here.

Comment: See http://www.reddit.com/r/redditdev